# Encrypt a local file using Flex or Actionscirpt or AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, encryption

I want to encrypt a local file using Adobe Flex, Actionscript or Air... help me.

...or I would like to know of other options but not vc++ or activeX.
I would like cross-platform operation.
Would you think it together?,

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a quick easy solution to encrypted a file with AIR, you might try to read the file into your AIR program... Then, store the bits as a bytearray in AIR's Encrypted Local Store.

The Adobe doc can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html), - also note - there is a warning about performance should the encrypted local store grow to larger that 10 MBs.

```
// Read file contents as fileData

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes(fileData);
EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("filename", bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Air seems like a reasonable option. It's the only Flash-based product with decent local file access.

This library will definitely be helpful: http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

If you don't want to look at any C/C++ based stuff and need x-platform powers, Java might be a next best choice.